# On-Error Action and Error Rule in Datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a request rule where I am doing parallel call (two backends) using match --> skip-backside--> request XSL --> on-error(continue) --> results action --> event-sink --> response XSL --> results.

I am supposed to continue the flow when any of the call fails, treating it as partial success. But if both fails - error rule should be triggered.

Issue is that in above request rule design, partial success is working fine i.e., if any of the two call fails it is treated as partial success and flow continues. But if both calls are failing, then instead of aborting the flow and calling error rule, it is still completing the request rule and exiting. I tried placing on-error(abort) after response XSL but it is not useful as call still exits through request rule.

How can I call error rule from above request rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it but I think that you would have to call another rule and check the response from that if both calls fail.

Or make it easier for yourself and use Gatewayscript where you simply can add a try/catch to check the resulting requests.